# DataTables - filtering based on time span

Tags: datatables

I have a column with data, within the datatables, similar to the below:

```
0500-1300
0500-1430
0600-0915
0600-1000
0600-1100
0600-1115
0600-1130
0600-1200
0600-1215
0600-1300
0600-1315
```

I would like a filter not too dissimilar from http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_bootstrap_time.html where someone can pick a FROM time and a TO time, which would then filter the data.

Let's say say someone chooses:

```
FROM: 0600
TO: 1100
```

Then only 3 would show. However if I chose:

```
FROM: 0500
TO: 1400
```

All would show. Is such a thing possible? Would the plugin from the site above be what I am after?

Comment: Think you're looking at writing your own here, though it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I'm thinking of splitting the time to 2 hidden columns and filtering on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const timeStringToInt = (time) => {
  const hoursMinutes = time.split(/[.:]/);
  const hours = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10) * 60;
  var minutes = parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10);
  return hours + minutes;
}

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  (settings, data, dataIndex) => {
    const min = timeStringToInt($('#timeFrom').val());
    const max = timeStringToInt($('#timeTo').val());
    const start = timeStringToInt(data[0]);
    const end = timeStringToInt(data[1]);
    return start >= min && end <= max;
  }
);
```

You might need to alter your function depending upon the position of the hours columns. Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/2zrzt6hf/).

EDIT

After looking at your data a little more I made a mistake in my initial answer, this should do it:

```
const timeStringToInt = (time) => {
  const hoursMinutes = time.split(":");
  const hours = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10) * 60;
  var minutes = parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10);
  return hours + minutes;
}
const stringToInt = (time) => {
  var minutes = parseInt(time.slice(-2), 10);
  const hours = parseInt(time.slice(0, -2), 10) * 60;
  return hours + minutes;
}

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  (settings, data, dataIndex) => {
    const min = timeStringToInt($('#timeFrom').val());
    const max = timeStringToInt($('#timeTo').val());
    const timeParts = data[0].split("-");
    const start = stringToInt(timeParts[0]);
    const end = stringToInt(timeParts[1]);
    return start >= min && end <= max;
  }
);
```

Updated JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lfk3s0Lo/).

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: So close :-) getting "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" when I do it locally but sure I've done something wrong